# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level - existing answers don't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 web site, and have changed the project file to build the views when building in release mode...

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
  ...other stuff elided for clarity
<PropertyGroup/>
```

This was working fine until I added a deploy package, and discovered a mistake in the Web.Release.config file where it transforms the connection string.

I fixed that, and now when I build in release mode, I get the error...

*It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS*

I've searched around for this, but most of the answers seem to be one of...

1) Change the IIS configuration - not relevant to me as this is when building

2) Look for extra web.config files - there aren't any

3) Delete the obj directory and rebuild - didn't help

I can change the MvcBuildViews entry in the project file to false, and it builds fine. As soon as I change it back to true, I get this error.

I've tried reverting everything back to where it was before, but it doesn't help.

I've added this project file entry before, as it's important to me to have the views built (catches errors that can otherwise get missed), and have never seen this error before.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Check if you have some web.config located in sub folders which might trigger such an error.

Comment: @LexLi please see my comment 2, where I already pointed out that there aren't any.

Comment: Then you need to share more data, such as the web project settings.

Comment: What do you need to know? The web project settings are all at their default,s except I switched off "Enable edit and continue." It's set to start on the current page, "Apply server settings to all users" is checked, and it's using IIS Express with an URL of http://localhost:23828/. Out of the checkboxes at the bottom, only ASP.NET is checked. Do you need to know anything else? Thanks

Comment: It would be good enough if you show the complete error page. Usually the 500 error page will show which config file at which line contains the error.

Comment: Huh? If you read my original post, you'll see that the error is at COMPILE time, there's no 500 error page as I don't get anywhere near running the code. If I compile in Debug mode all is OK, but if I compile in Release mode, I get the compiler error shown.

Comment: Even at compile time the page is transferred on the wire and can be usually captured via netsh. If that's some magic you never know, now it's the time to study it.

Comment: Can you explain that please? I am talking about when I'm in Visual Studio, and I compile the MVC project. What gets transferred across what wire, and to where? I don't claim to be an expert on this stuff, but as far as I understood, compiling merely builds the DLLs from the source code. I wasn't aware that anything got transferred across any network, and even if it did, I wouldn't have any idea what was trying to view the transferred data that could show a 500 page. Please clarify.

Comment: Blog posts such as [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2012/12/01/network-tracing-packet-sniffing-built-in-to-windows-server-2008-r2-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) document how to use netsh along with Network Monitor to analyze network packets on the wire. No matter where the packets are sent, in VS or not, Windows allows you to capture them. That's what I meant if you don't understand.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you are so convinced that anything is being sent out on the network, when the error comes from msbuild. This is a compile issue, nothing to do with any network. The solution doesn't compile. Why are you so convinced that msbuild is sending data out of the network?